# highlighting and coloring differently a specific section of data using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data and I have been able to put it into a ggplot graph (time series data). The data is over 12 years and there are specific spikes in the data for certain periods (the data is in weeks). I would like to try and color code one particular week of each year where the spikes begin but do not know where to begin.

The idea that I have is that the spike occurs in January when the superbowl happens!, that would be the `week` column `2001-01-01 - 2001-31-01` Is it possible to subset a period using ggplot and color code the graph accordingly. So for the superbowl week use a different color?

i.e. each year `2001 - 2012` color code Jan `(01-01) to (01-31)` red for example. That is 4 weeks of data. What I currently have is;

```
df[, .(df_sales = (sum(qty) * (EUR))), by = week] %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week, y = df_sales)) +
  labs(x = 'wks', title = 'TS plot of qty x eur')
```

Which gives me a nice plot but I would like to color code the spikes (i.e. my hypothsis that they occur in January, week of the superbowl). I can post the graph for clarification if necessary.

```
     ID     unit  qty    NA    EUR     KEY      identity       week
1: 1123539 1147     1     GR    2.39  652159 10090100003 2001-08-20
2: 3102228 1129     1     GR    2.15  257871 10090100003 2001-04-16
3: 3321265 1129     1     GR    2.15  257871 10090100003 2001-04-16
4: 3321265 1122     1     GR    2.15  257871 10090100004 2001-02-26
5: 1120774 1151     1     GR    2.39  213290 10090100005 2001-09-17
6: 1145763 1157     1     GR    2.39  213290 10090100005 2001-10-29
```

EDIT: I attach the graph for clarification [image]

EDIT2: I attach the new graph[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a second `geom` in conjunction with `subset` like this :

```
library(lubridate)
ggplot(df, aes(x = week, y = df_sales)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_bar(data = subset(df, month(week) == "1"), stat = "identity", col = "red") +
  labs(x = 'wks', title = 'TS plot of qty x eur')
```

Here we use `lubridate::month` to check which row belongs to a week in January.

For some fictional random data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks great and is exactly what I am after. When I try to replicate this on my own data I am only able to plot the red parts, i.e the January parts `g <- total[, .(total_sales = (sum(UNITS) * (DOLLARS))), by = DATE] %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DATE, y = total_sales)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(total, month(DATE) == "1"), stat = "identity", col = "red") +
    geom_bar(fill = 'steelblue', stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = 'Week', title = 'Sales (qt * P) 12 Years')
g`

Comment: I edit my original question with the January output.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Maybe you should separate the steps of creating the data and plotting.

Comment: Thanks anways, the results look great regardless :) I will try separating as you suggested